# haxeUI projects won't compile for windows / error C2259 : cannot instantiate abstract class

Tags: haxe, openfl, haxeui

The following example code compiles and runs with neko, but returns an error message when attempting to compile to windows:

```
import haxe.ui.toolkit.core.Toolkit;
import haxe.ui.toolkit.core.Root;
import haxe.ui.toolkit.core.interfaces.IDisplayObject;
import Sys.println;

class Main {
   public static function main() {

      Toolkit.openFullscreen(function(root:Root) {

      });
      println('test program has run...');
   }
}
```

The error message I receive means nothing to me (there is more, but it seems to repeat):

> ./src/haxe/ui/toolkit/core/renderers/ItemRenderer.cpp(161) : error C2259: 'haxe::ui::toolkit::core::interfaces::IStyleableDisplayObject_delegate_' : cannot instantiate abstract class
>           with
>           [
>               IMPL=haxe::ui::toolkit::core::renderers::ItemRenderer_obj
>           ]
>           due to following members:
>           'Void haxe::ui::toolkit::core::interfaces::IDisplayObject_obj::addEventListener(String,Dynamic,hx::Null,hx::Null,hx::Null)' : is abstract
>           with
>           [
>               T=bool
>           ]
>           include\haxe/ui/toolkit/core/interfaces/IDisplayObject.h(127) : see declaration of 'haxe::ui::toolkit::core::interfaces::IDisplayObject_obj::addEventListener'
>           'Dynamic haxe::ui::toolkit::core::interfaces::IDisplayObject_obj::addEventListener_dyn(void)' : is abstract
>           include\haxe/ui/toolkit/core/interfaces/IDisplayObject.h(128) : see declaration of 'haxe::ui::toolkit::core::interfaces::IDisplayObject_obj::addEventListener_dyn'
>           'bool haxe::ui::toolkit::core::interfaces::IDisplayObject_obj::dispatchEvent(openfl::_legacy::events::Event)' : is abstract
>           include\haxe/ui/toolkit/core/interfaces/IDisplayObject.h(129) : see declaration of 'haxe::ui::toolkit::core::interfaces::IDisplayObject_obj::dispatchEvent'
>           'Dynamic haxe::ui::toolkit::core::interfaces::IDisplayObject_obj::dispatchEvent_dyn(void)' : is abstract
>           include\haxe/ui/toolkit/core/interfaces/IDisplayObject.h(130) : see declaration of 'haxe::ui::toolkit::core::interfaces::IDisplayObject_obj::dispatchEvent_dyn'
>           'bool haxe::ui::toolkit::core::interfaces::IDisplayObject_obj::hasEventListener(String)' : is abstract
>           include\haxe/ui/toolkit/core/interfaces/IDisplayObject.h(131) : see declaration of 'haxe::ui::toolkit::core::interfaces::IDisplayObject_obj::hasEventListener'
>           'Dynamic haxe::ui::toolkit::core::interfaces::IDisplayObject_obj::hasEventListener_dyn(void)' : is abstract
>           include\haxe/ui/toolkit/core/interfaces/IDisplayObject.h(132) : see declaration of 'haxe::ui::toolkit::core::interfaces::IDisplayObject_obj::hasEventListener_dyn'

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of haxe are you using?

Comment: haxelib version returns 3.2.0-rc.3. I have no problem compiling projects that don't use haxeui to windows exe files, so I assume I have all the necessary cpp packages etc.

Comment: what does just "haxe" return as the version? You should see something like: `Haxe Compiler 3.2.0 - (C)2005-2015 Haxe Foundation
 Usage : haxe.exe -main <class> [-swf|-js|-neko|-php|-cpp|-as3] <output> [options]`

Comment: Apologies, thought haxelib was the same thing - that returns "Haxe Compiler 3.2.1 -(C)2005-2015 Haxe Foundation Usage : haxe.exe -main <class> [-swf | -js | -neko | -php | -cpp | -as3] <output> [options]

Answer (score 2):

It is a problem with Haxe 3.2.1.

If you downgrade to 3.2.0 then it should work.

Comment: Is there a haxe/hxcpp issue opened to track this 3.2.1 bug? I would like to look into fixing it.

Comment: It is reported in [haxeui](https://github.com/ianharrigan/haxeui/issues/282). It seems that the problem is related to [issue #4454](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues/4454) in haxe. I haven't checked with nightly builds if it works now.